# How to access and use skeleton joint coordinates using OpenNI, ASUS Xtion, and ROS?

Tags: xtion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To develop a person follower robot, I am using ASUS Xtion and OpenNI. To obtain both RGB image and skeleton joints, I am using a skeleton tracker script (https://github.com/Chaos84/skeleton_tracker). Tracker publishes joints in "/tf" But the thing is that I cannot use those joint coordinates in my script. I don't know how to access them. How can I access and use them in my script to make the robot move according to those coordinates? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232598/how-to-access-and-use-skeleton-joint-coordinates-using-openni,-asus-xtion,-and-ros?/) by [gokay](https://answers.ros.org/users/26672/gokay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The information you are interested in that is contained in the `/tf` data will be transformations from some frame on the Kinect to some frame on the user (e.g. right_hand). What you need to do is write a node that creates a tf listener that periodically looks up this transform data. Here are the tutorials on tf listeners in [Python](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28Python%29) and [C++](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29). Once you have that transformation information, it's up to you to decide what to do with it. For example, you could publish the relevant geometric information on a new topic that a robot control node subscribes to. Or you could directly control the robot in the node with the tf listener.

**EDIT**

The above links aren't working (seems like a bug in Askbot or Askbot config)... they work in my preview window. Here are the links:

Python: http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20(Python)

C++: http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20(C%2B%2B)

**EDIT 2**

Fixed links using answer from @joq [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/12729/how-to-link-urls-with-parentheses-correctly/).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0